# How to get unmatched column from two dataframe in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

i have two data frame `df1` and `df2`, i want only unmatched column in the  result. i tried to do do using SQL but SQL returns all column not one.

```
df1 

col1|col2|col3
a     b    c
1     2    3

df2
col1|col2|col3
a     b    e
1     2    3
```

what i want is if it can return

```
df3
col3
```

Is it possible to do in pyspark to do or I have to compare by selecting each column from both the data frame and then compare?

Comment: When the columns are different, which column do you want? The column from df1 or df2?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is compare the names of columns between two dataframes, I would suggest the following.

```
df3 = ## Create empty pyspark dataframe
for name_1, name_2 in zip(df1.schema.names, df2.schema.names):
    if name_1 != name_2:
         df3[name_2] = df2.name_2
```

Comment: each data frame has dynamic column number and name  and columns are more than 100. i was using df3 = df1.subtract(df2) but it is giving al unmatched row. i can achieve this nested if else but that takes time. is there any way that it give mismatch column

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really specify from which dataframe you want to show columns. Below solution will show you where you have differences at the same row level between both dataframes. Assuming as in your dfs, that there are no nulls earlier.

```
val df11 = df1.withColumn("id", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("col1")))
val df22 = df2.withColumn("id", row_number().over(Window.orderBy("col1")))
val df_join = df11.join(df22.selectExpr("col1 as col11", "col2 as col22", "col3 as col33", "id"), Seq("id"), "inner")
df_join.select(when($"col1" === $"col11", null).otherwise(col("col1")), when($"col2" === $"col22", null).otherwise(col("col2")), when($"col3" === $"col33", null).otherwise(col("col3"))).show
```